# Exponential fit - sum of exponentials

Tags: curve-fitting, exponential

I want to fit the following data:

```
x(time) y(data)    
0.75;   19.33    
1;      19.04   
1.25;   17.21   
1.5;    12.98   
1.75;   11.59   
2;  9.26   
2.25;   7.66   
2.5;    6.59    
2.75;   5.68    
3;  5.1    
3.25;   4.36   
3.5;    4.43     
3.75;   3.58    
4;  3.01    
4.25;   3.24     
4.5;    3.58     
4.75;   3.13     
5;  3.88     
5.25;   3.19     
5.5;    3.58     
5.75;   3.64
```

using the following code:

```
#read text file
data = pd.read_table('episode_5_prova.txt', sep='\t')
#DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Define your function
def func(x, a, b, c, d, e):
return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c*np.exp(-d*x) + e

#convert dataframe into numpy array
df0=df['time']
x=df0.as_matrix()
df1=df['bi']
y=df1.as_matrix()

# Using the python scipy function curve_fit with function and input variables
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
a, b, c, d, e= popt
fit = func(x, a, b, c, d, e)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, fit, color='r', lw=3)
ax.plot(x, y,'g.')
observed_values=scipy.array(y)
expected_values=scipy.array(fit)
plt.xlim(0,25)
plt.ylim(0,20)

print(a,b,c,d,e)

print(scipy.stats.chisquare(observed_values, f_exp=expected_values, ddof=3))
plt.show()
```

I obtain the following plot:
[first fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6BDY.png)
However, for the purpose of my work, I need to fix my parameters b and c as:
b=0.000431062, d=0.000580525 but i don't obtained a good fit as follows:
[second fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRoc6.png)

Does anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: you can just copy/paste a bit of your text file into the text body of your question so we can see an example of your input

Comment: Is it ok like this ? Thanks

Comment: Your posted data shows the first two data points with nearly the same Y value, but I do not see this on the plots. Would you please verify this?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i cutted in the plots. Anyway, i solved the problem…it was a mistake concerning the conversion of time...The problem is i obtained fit parameters with a standard deviation very high...i don't how to get a more accurated fit parameters

Comment: would you please edit the post with updated data with the new time conversion?

Comment: Wait, do you want to fix parameters `b` and `c` or `b` and `d`?  If `b`  and `c`, there is only one variable that is exponential.  More importantly, If you mean `b` and `d`, then the fit is **linear**, depending only on `a`, `c` and `d`, and can be solved by basic (and direct, not iterative) regression methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3808325/605948).

In short, you need an eigenvalue solver, a least squares solver and follow the steps outlined in the solution.

There is [Matlab code](https://octave-online.net/bucket%7EMCyrH7H4QD7qcE46BJgk6P) available that you can use as an example to implement in other languages (e.g. Python).

```
clear all;
clc;
% get data
dx = 0.02;
x  = (dx:dx:1.5)';
y  =  5*exp(0.5*x) + 4*exp(-3*x) + 2*exp(-2*x) - 3*exp(0.15*x);

% calculate integrals
iy1 = cumtrapz(x, y);
iy2 = cumtrapz(x, iy1);
iy3 = cumtrapz(x, iy2);
iy4 = cumtrapz(x, iy3);

% get exponentials lambdas
Y = [iy1, iy2, iy3, iy4, x.^3, x.^2, x, ones(size(x))];
A = pinv(Y)*y;
%lambdas =
%  -2.9991
%  -1.9997
%   0.5000
%   0.1500

lambdas = eig([A(1), A(2), A(3), A(4); 1, 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1, 0]);
lambdas

% get exponentials multipliers
X = [exp(lambdas(1)*x), exp(lambdas(2)*x), exp(lambdas(3)*x), exp(lambdas(4)*x)];
P = pinv(X)*y;
P
%P =
%   4.0042
%   1.9955
%   4.9998
%  -2.9996
```